# Permission issues with mounted new hard drive on Ubuntu machine

Tags: 10.04, mount, permissions, hard-drive

I recently purchased a new hard drive, for the sole purpose of storing a database. I am running Ubuntu 10.0.4.

Since I had not done this sort of thing before, I decided to use the GUI (Disk Utility) to format and mount the disk (to avoid any snarfus caused by typos etc at the command line).

I correctly identified the new drive and proceeded as follows:

1. Elected to format the drive
2. Selected type: 'Ext4'
3. Selected the 'Take ownership of filesystem' checkbox
4. Unchecked the 'encrypt underlying device' checkbox
5. Provided a name for the new volume (mydata)

Once the device had been formatted, I then mounted the device as follows:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mydata
```

I created the directory /mydata/pgdbdata

and changed ownership as follows

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /mydata/pgdbdata
```

I check:

```
username@localhost:~$ ls -l /mydata/
total 20
drwx------ 2 root     root     16384 2012-06-19 23:05 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres  4096 2012-06-20 19:04 pgdbdata
```

However when I change to postgres user:

```
username@localhost:~$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@localhost:~$ ls -l /mydata/
ls: cannot open directory /mydata/: Permission denied
```

Because of this permissions issue, I can start the postgresql service and I can't create the postgresql db cluster. I am stuck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From your question I suppose that /media/market_data/ is owned by user and group root. `pgdbdata` folder has been only chowned to user and group postgres. But you are checking a wrong folder?

Comment: @pl1nk: Sorry. That was a typo. I have corrected the text in my question.

Comment: You should change the permissions of /mydata/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only changed permission of `pgdbdata` but not of `mydata` you should be able to do a `ls -l /mydata/pgdbdata` but if your postgresql user wants to see the content of `mydata` it has to have read access to that too.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why or how I missed that ... Nothing like a second pair of eyes ... :)

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes you're just blind. Happens to me all the time ;-)